# $\int_0^\infty(\mathrm{erf}^2(cx)\exp(-x^2)x^2\,dx$,$c \in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: calculus, integration, error-function

Does someone know useful formulae that might help evaluating this integral?

$$\int_0^\infty\mathrm{erf}^2(cx)\exp(-x^2)x^2\,dx,\quad c \in\mathbb{C}$$

Comment: Take a look here http://129.81.170.14/~vhm/papers_html/final19.pdf

Comment: You can "reduce" the integral to $$\frac{3}{4 \sqrt{\pi}} c^2 \int_0^1 dx \, \int_0^1 dy \, \left [1+c^2(x^2+y^2) \right ]^{-5/2} $$

Comment: @RonGordon Can you explain how?

Comment: Use the definition of the erf and change the order of integration.

Comment: Do you differentiate with respect to c? Else, I don't see how you get from my integral to yours.

Answer (score 2):

Your integral (let's call it $J(c)$) is
$${\frac {\arctan \left( \sqrt {2\,{c}^{2}+1} \right) }{\sqrt {\pi}}}-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}
4+{\frac {{c}^{2}}{\sqrt {\pi (2\,{c}^{2}+1)}
 \left( {c}^{2}+1 \right) }}
$$

at least for real $c$, where the integral converges.  Note that

$$ \dfrac{dJ}{dc} = {\frac {5\,{c}^{3}+3\,c}{\sqrt {\pi} \left( 2\,{c}^{2}+1 \right) ^{3/2
} \left( {c}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}}
$$
and integrate...

Comment: $dJ/dc$ looks like an unpleasant integral itself.  Why bother?

Comment: It's considerably less unpleasant, because it only has $\text{erf}(cx)$ rather than $\text{erf}(cx)^2$, and it has $x$ to an odd power.  You can integrate by parts.

Comment: How do you get $J(c)$?

Comment: To integrate ${\frac {5\,{c}^{3}+3\,c}{ \left( 2\,{c}^{2}+1 \right) ^{3/2} \left( {c
}^{2}+1 \right) ^{2}}}$, you can substitute $u =  \sqrt{2c^2+1}$ and get the integral of a rational function.